# CORS errors with Sabre API v2 calls

Tags: sabre

For the last few weeks, we started getting CORS errors when trying to retrieve the auth token v2 API. We installed chrome CORS plugin and got that to work for now but then the flight fares API started giving CORS errors, we tried providing the regular cors headers in the request but to no avail. here is what is seen in the developer console. I am sending a GET request for the flight fares and tried the regular CORS headers as well but to no avail..

var getFlightFares = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: mainURL + "/v2/shop/flights/fares",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept': "*/*"
                    //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    //'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
                    //'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
                }
            };

### Result in developer console

GET 
http://127.0.0.1:8080/spa/images/flights/sm%7B%7Bcheckout1.returnAirlineCode%7D%7D.gif [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]

OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://api.test.sabre.com/v2/auth/token [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 623ms]

POST 
XHR 
https://api.test.sabre.com/v2/auth/token [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 152ms]
Response : 
 Object { data: Object, status: 200, headers: dd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "OK" }  sabre_integration.js:311:5
tokenT1RLAQJyP+PPcbBSEiIy9JBZrGkt4nu/dBD6CkzcyWI0njOM/Bbn3ngcAADA961ZaE1tN5y/bu57k0DseB5ocYDY9AIj64EwVJOr4RYAHKZF+H8tL7QnM35wjKYr40yjxkp1XL8lRDx84B+whxOMTaDreGnp1tDtFPhCGilvfeFpuXawbf1PjWAsR0uoNE9c0Pnmk8qWwuYEgNEkODYs8+K/peXF97LqylCFC6MWmkyodwSGwH7D/hjD5wTcSqJGLvARwo2NY/hplnArn8rY3sZ9gN3JV5PhqyPks56PYyD0Y5WvABg8YOVEA/Ud  sabre_integration.js:312:5

OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://api.test.sabre.com/v2/shop/flights/fares [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 100ms]
Headers
Params
Response
departuredate2016-12-06destinationLAXlengthofstay5originJFKpointofsalecountryUS

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.test.sabre.com/v2/shop/flights/fares?origin=JFK&destination=LAX&departuredate=2016-12-06&lengthofstay=5&pointofsalecountry=US. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).  (unknown)
GET 
http://127.0.0.1:8080/spa/images/flight_listing_sprite.png [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 33ms]

Comment: CORS are normally handle in server rather clent side. you can configure data providing server from which domain the data can be accessed.

Comment: Was the issue not with auth token endpoint API? The same GET on my side works fine...are you sure your client is not doing something? There should not be a need to specify the content type, only the Authorization Bearer.

Comment: Our code was working fine and suddenly we started getting CORS errors. I updated the original problem description above with the latest output from the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening google chrome from command prompt with the commands: 
"chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/path/to/foo"
check there then